# Upstart script not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, upstart

I'm trying to write an upstart script to start orbited on startup. The script is as follows:

```
#orbited
start on startup
stop on shutdown
script
        exec /usr/local/bin/orbited --config=/etc/orbited.cfg
end script
```

When I run upstart orbited I get something like this:

```
orbited start/running, process 605
```

But when I run status orbited right after doing that I get:

```
orbited stop/waiting
```

The script fails to start even though it says it's running. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: I figured out through the orbited logs that it was exiting with an error. There was no user called "orbited." I fixed that and it will now start when I manually send "start orbited" but it's not starting automatically on bootup. Progress is progress anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to remove exec from your script. It does the same thing as putting the script brackets. Should look like

```
script
     /usr/local/bin/orbited --config=/etc/orbited.cfg
end script
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried that and it's still behaving the same way.

Comment: Okay, I figured out that it wasn't starting because orbited didn't have a user set up in the config file. Now it'll start when I tell it to in the upstart script, but it won't start automatically on bootup.

Comment: Er, how about retaining `exec` and removing the `script` block?